# DHCP lease for raspberry pi not found

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

This question is semi - related to this one: [Networking - Shared to other Computers - How to find a client's IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/q/849102/295286)

My setup is such that I'm using laptop as ethernet gateway, and raspberry is a host. In the linked question, my answer has Wireshark capture screenshot clearly shows that there is DHCP request going to my laptop from raspberry and there is response. So far so good !

Many answers on the internet suggest to check `/var/lib/NetworkManager/` directory or `/var/lib/dhcp` directory for the leases. Problem is that in all my searches I found only leases for IP addresses that were *given to my laptop*. What I am interested in is finding a record of lease that my  *laptop gave to raspberry*.

And you can take my word for it - I've searched almost everything, didn't find nothing, but for the sake of being consistent and documenting everything, here's my `grep` search results . . .which are basically nothing.

```
$ grep -R '10.42.0.40' /var/lib/NetworkManager/                             
grep: /var/lib/NetworkManager/secret_key: Permission denied

$ sudo grep -R '10.42.0.40' /var/lib/NetworkManager/                        
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

$ sudo grep -R '10.42.0.40' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/         
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

$ sudo grep -R '10.42.0.40' /var/lib/dhcp/                                  
[sudo] password for xieerqi:
```

Output of `netstat` requested by muru:

```
$ sudo netstat -unlp | grep -w 67                                           
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           14866/dnsmasq   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1696/dnsmasq
```

Comment: What's your DHCP server software? `isc-dhcp-server`?  Maybe whatever's listening on UDP port 67 should tell you what program's logs you should check (`sudo netstat -unlp | grep -w 67`).

Comment: @muru got dnsmasq there

Comment: http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2010q3/004384.html or https://www.clearos.com/clearfoundation/social/community/nothing-in-dhcp-server-leases-list any use?

Comment: @muru AHA, found it !!! it;s in `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases` Feel free to write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `netstat` output shows `dnsmasq` is the DHC server here, [this mailing list post](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2010q3/004384.html) suggests `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases` as the file where leases are stored.